# How to control HTTP navigation step by step?

Tags: https, single-sign-on

In Google chrome, we can see the HTTP navigation using Developer tools > Network > Preserve Log. But using this I cannot control the navigation step by step.
Is there any way with/without developer tools wherein we can control the HTTP navigation step by step for better investigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http only have two options to communicate with the server

- request (HttpRequest)
- response (HttpResponse)

The browser only send request and then wait for the response. Nothing happens in between them. Once the request is processed, it returns response code, header, response.

Browser tracks how much time it took, what kind of header send with the request etc.

Comment: Thank you for inputs Aniruddha! Is it possible to control this navigation flow step by step similar to what we do when using breakpoint? I am troubleshooting an Single Sign-On redirect issue and there I see that it all goes very quickly.

Comment: you can put break points in your code before it going to server and coming after server to debug all of them. You cannot debug the server code in the browser. but if you handles back end like java or php you can put break point there too.

Comment: Thank you Aniruddha, I got clarity now :-)